# Get a cross-validated scaled training set from R vtreat

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I'm using R package vtreat to prepare some data. As I have several categorical variables, and the size of my dataset is not large enough to split it into 3 groups, I'm using cross-validation to do the pre-processing step.

```
prep  = mkCrossFrameCExperiment(
dframe = newTrain,
varlist = allVars,
outcomename = "RESULT",
ncross = 10,
verbose = T,
outcometarget = "Realizada",
catScaling = T,
rareCount = round(min(table(newTrain$RESULT)) * 0.01)

)
treatments <- prep$treatments

#Variable Screaning
pruneSig <- 1 / length(allVars)
vf = value_variables_C(
dframe = prep$crossFrame,
varlist = treatments$scoreFrame$varName,
outcomename = "RESULT",
outcometarget = "Realizada",
ncross = 10,
verbose = T,
catScaling = T,
rareCount = round(min(table(newTrain$RESULT)) *
                    0.01)
)
newvars <- vf$var[vf$sig <= pruneSig]

dTrainTreated <- prep$crossFrame
dTestTreated <- vtreat::prepare(treatments,
                              testData,
                              pruneSig = c(), catScaling = T,
                              varRestriction = newvars)
```

However, I realized that althought my test set gets scaled, my training set doesn't. Furthermore, as far as I understand, if I do `vtreat::prepare(treatments,trainData)` I loose all the power of cross-validation...

Is there a way to get a cross-validated set with scaled variables on vtreat?